# What South American country was the body of water in?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-boys-from-brazil

In *The Boys from Brazil,* Barry Kohler is first spying on the Nazis in Paraguay, and then on the run from them. While he is on the run, there is a scene where we see a large body of water in the background, all the way to the horizon, looking like a sea or ocean. But Paraguay is a landlocked country.

Is Barry supposed to have run to a different South American country? Or is it a goof? (I know the Paraguay scenes were filmed in Portugal, so maybe the Atlantic Ocean got in the picture by mistake.)

Comment: Probably a goof. Doesn't seem important to the plot.

Comment: You're probably right. Still, maybe it could be a big lake. (I once saw water all the way to the southern horizon from the Oakland Bay Bridge. So, if there are any lakes over ten or so miles long in Paraguay ...)